# Calculating the Count of a related Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have two models Professionals and Projects

> Professionals hasMany Projects
>
> Projects belongsTo Professionals

In the Professionals index page i need to show the number of projects the Professional has.

Right now i am doing the following query to get all the Professionals.
How can i fetch the count of the Projects of each of the Professionals as well.

```
@pros = Professionals.all.asc(:name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add projects_count to Professional

Then

```
class Project
  belongs_to :professional, counter_cache: true
end
```

And rails will handle the count every time a project is added to or removed from a professional.  Then you can just do .projects_count on each professional.

Edit:
If you actually want additonal data

```
@pros = Professionals.includes(:projects).order(:name)
```

Then

```
@pros.each do |pro|
  pro.name
  pro.projects.each do |project|
    project.name
  end
end
```

Comment: lets say if i wanted some data from a related table lets say Professionals and the names of all the projects of his. how would u do do that in MongoDb? i come from RDMS :/

Comment: Updated answer.  I don't use mongodb but don't see why it should be any different.

Comment: @HarshaMV MongoDB doesn't have joins. If you want to cross information from multiple collections you have to do it client side.

Comment: Oh.  In which case I guess he'll have to do at least 2 queries.

Comment: @Baloo indeed. If he has N Professionals he would have to do N+1 queries - one to fetch the professionals and N to fetch the projects count for each professional. Another option is to do an aggregation in the projects collection by professional which would calc the count of projects for each professional in a single operation. Nevertheless, the joining of the data gathered in each collection is always client side.

Comment: @joao thanks a lot. Can you point me to any example on how i can nest and build the data for the views? right now i am doing a call from the views to fetch the details of all the projects and looping to show it. isnt this against the mvc?

Comment: @HarshaMV my understanding of ruby on rails is very limited, I can only give you a sort of pseudo code for the mongoDB queries. Perhaps someone with the necessary knowledge will answer your question (if you are in a hurry starting a bounty might help).

Comment: @joao Was my pseuedo code enough? As the general point there is that suggesting to iterate through results is not the right way to proceed. I also have other things to do than dive into internals of frameworks I do not use. But there should be a logical way to make the database do the work. SQL or NoSQL. It doesn't matter. Don't run away to client side code to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I am just abstracting here because the rails thing really isn't my bag. But let's talk about schema and things to look for. And as such the **code** is really just "pseudo-code" but should be *close* to what is wanted.

Considering "just" how MongoDB is going to store the data, and that you presumably seem to have multiple collections. And I am not saying that is or is not the **best** model, but just dealing with it.

Let us assume we have this data for "Projects"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53202e1d78166396592cf805"),
    "name": "Project1,
    "desc": "Building Project"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532197fb423c37c0edbd4a52")
    "name": "Project2",
    "desc": "Renovation Project"
}
```

And that for "Professionals" we might have something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("531e22b7ba53b9dd07756bc8"),
    "name": "Steve",
    "projects": [
        ObjectId("53202e1d78166396592cf805"),
        ObjectId("532197fb423c37c0edbd4a52")
    ]
}
```

Right. So now we see that the "Professional" has to have some kind of concept that there are related items in another collection and what those related items are.

Now I presume, (and it's not my bag) that there is a way to get down to the lower level of the driver implementation in Mongoid ( I believe that is Moped off the top of my head ) and that it likely ( from memory ) is invoked in a similar way to ( asssuming "Professionals" as the class model name ) :

```
Professionals.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$projects" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
])
```

Or in some similar form that is more or less the analog to what you would do in the native mongodb shell. The point being, with something like this you just made the **server** do the work, rather than pulling all the results to you **client** and looping through them.

Suggesting that you use native code to iterate results from your data store is counter productive and counter intuitive do using any kind of back end database store. Whether it by a SQL database or a NoSQL database, the general preference is as long as the database has methods to do the aggregation work, then use them.

If you are writing code that essentially pulls every record from your store and then cycles through to get the result then you are doing something wrong.

**Use** the database methods. Otherwise you might as well just use a text file and be done with it.

Comment: Yes, you have a point. Nevertheless, what I had in mind was that if he wanted to cross data with another collection (for instance, showing the project names or other data for each user), it would be client side (I'm not saying it is good or bad, that depends on the case). But that is clearly a deviation from the original question. Also, upvoted this answer because it solves the real problem here.